# MS Excel and Access XML Large Data Import

Tags: xml, excel

I have an XML file (stackoverflow post data) that I need to be able to run queries on for a data project.  I have tried importing the XML file into both Access and Excel, but the only problem is, the XML file is 30+ gigabytes.  Nothing happened when I imported it to Access, and my computer (school computer) stopped working when I tried Excel.  Is there any way to open and run queries on an XML file of this size?

Link to XML file (It is compressed to ~6 gigabytes in a 7z file)
https://archive.org/download/stackexchange

https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z

Answer (score 0):

Hey problem with your data set is it is very big. So you can process it using pull based XML parsing easily. Using this type you can easily traverse all the XML elements without eating up all the memory. Use StAX API for XML processing.

Event based StAX processing is very convenient to use for this task. Get started here.
http://www.360doc.com/content/12/1126/19/820209_250389830.shtml 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-stax1/index.html